# D3 v4 - d3.zoom() prevents binding some events except on the Window

Tags: javascript, d3.js

*Unhelpful Github [discussion](https://github.com/d3/d3/issues/2887) led me to ask this question here:*

---

After changing to the new v4.0 D3, seems like using `d3.zoom()` [blocks some events](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom#api-reference), like:

Calling this:

```
svg.call(d3.zoom()
     .scaleExtent([1, 40])
     .translateExtent([[-100, -100], [width + 90, height + 100]])
     .on("zoom", zoomed));
```

And then this:

```
document.querySelector('svg').addEventListener('mouseup', function(){ alert(1) })
```

Won't alert anything when clicking anywhere on the SVG.

I really *don't* want to do:

```
window.addEventListener("mouseup", function(e){
    if( [target or target parent is the specific SVG element] ){
        // do something
    }
}
```

Because this will introduce a global non-namespaced event `mouseup` on the window (this technique seems to *only* work on the `window` object) and this event might be removed somewhere else, or happen multiple times. (It isn't easy to encapsulate it, or I simply don't know how).

Any better ideas on how to capture `mouseup` events on the SVG?

---

Related to another question of mine: [Event capturing namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38572501/104380)

#### [Demo page](https://jsfiddle.net/fqq6g8ms/6/)

---

### Update:

With the help of Mark's answer, here's the [working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/fqq6g8ms/12/)

Comment: Is your ultimate goal here to capture a `mouseup` on the `svg` or on the `circle`?

Comment: @Mark on the `svg`

Comment: Wouldn't that just be the zoom `end` event?

Comment: @Mark - no..there is no `zoom` function trigger , try it yourself in the demo page.

Comment: The `zoom` adds a pan event, mousedown starts a pan (i.e. zoom `start`) and mouseup ends a pan (i.e. zoom `end`).  If you are enabling panning on the `svg`, you can determine if it's mouseup or a true pan by checking if the user moved the mouse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Still not sure I understand your intent, but you might be approaching this from the wrong angle.  Instead of trying to add your own events, just work within the events provided by the zoom behavior.  The zoom functionality provides for panning where mousedown starts a pan (i.e. zoom `start` event) and mouseup ends a pan (i.e. zoom `end` event).  So, the real question becomes, how can you differentiate a pan vs a "click" mouseup?  To do that, just check if the user moved the mouse:

```
svg.call(d3.zoom()
         .scaleExtent([1, 40])
         .translateExtent([[-100, -100], [width + 90, height + 100]])
         .on("start", zoomstart)
         .on("end", zoomend)
         .on("zoom", zoomed));

var mousePos = null;
function zoomstart(){
  mousePos = d3.mouse(this);
}

function zoomend(){
  var m = d3.mouse(this);
  if (mousePos[0] ===  m[0] && mousePos[1] === m[1]){
    alert('mouseup');
  }
}

function zoomed() {
  svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
  gX.call(xAxis.scale(d3.event.transform.rescaleX(x)));
  gY.call(yAxis.scale(d3.event.transform.rescaleY(y)));
}
```

Update [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fqq6g8ms/10/).

Comment: Thanks! all I needed was to bind the `end` event and run `if( d3.event.type == 'end' ){ [code for mouseup] }`.. who would have thought. D3 is the exact opposite to intuitive programming.